# МЕДВЕДЬ или как- то еще?

Tags: языкознание

Почему русское слово МЕДВЕДЬ в этим. словаре (ЭШС, Г.А.Крылов) определено, как эвфемизм, а не как обычное (*нетабуированное*) слово?

Разве не могли наши предки назвать лесного жителя, сосущего мед, просто МЕДВЕДЕМ?

Answer (score 3):

Медведь - эвфемизм *по происхождению*. Словарь Крылова все-таки этимологический, и там совершенно верно указана причина возникновения давно ставшего обыденным слова.

Мишку нельзя было поминать всуе и "придумали" это "мёд ведающий".

Как назывался медведь до того - тайна, покрытая мраком. Настолько прочно забылось это табуированное слово.
Возможно, в славянском существовало общееиндоевропейское "бэр", но недостоверно, ибо ни в одном славянском языке не сохранилось явных родственных. Версия о том, что *"берлога" - логово "бэра"*, не подтверждается этимологически (см. ниже), а других аргументов у сторонников славянского "бэра" в общем-то и нет.
Но то, что какое-то слово должно было существовать, общепризнано.

По поводу этимологии слова "берлога". Это отдельная и объемная тема. Ограничусь здесь цитатой из Вики.

> Существует множество версий происхождения слова. И. В. Ягич трактовал его значение как «выбранная стоянка», а М.Фасмер — как «лужа, грязь, мусор»[6].

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0

---

*Убрал совершенно ошибочные рассуждения, построенные на недоразумении гуглоперевода (почему-то он связывает медведя с носильщиком). Благо, разобрался быстро.*

Answer (score 3):

Комментарий для Федора. Решил в виде ответа оформить, потому что много цитат. Просьба не оценивать, ибо просто пояснение для конкретного участника.

Федор, свои рассуждения и мысли подкрепляйте всегда ссылками на авторитетные источники, ответ будет более солидным и защищенным. Да и Ваше личное мнение может быть скорректировано в ту или иную сторону.
Этимологический словарь Крылова :

> БУРЫЙ
> Заимствование из тюркских языков, где бур имеет значение "рыже-красный" и восходит (через персидский) к индоевропейскому **bher – "светло-коричневый**".

База Старостина :

> > Proto-IE: ***bher-**
> > Nostratic etymology: Nostratic etymology
> > Meaning: bear
> > Old Indian: bhalla-ḥ m., bhallaka- m., bhallū̆ka- m. `Bar̈' (< *bher-n-?)
> > Slavic:* bьrlog-ъ B, *bьrlogā
> > Baltic: ?* bē̂r-a- (1) adj.
> > Germanic: *bir-an- m.,* bir-ōn- f.; *bir-n-u- c.,* birn-iō f.; *bár-s-in- n.
> > Russ. meaning: зверек (**медведь**)

Английская этимология слова *brown*:

> > **brown** (adj.) Look up brown at Dictionary.com
> > Old English brun "dark, dusky," developing a definite color sense only 13c., from Proto-Germanic *brunaz (cognates: Old Norse brunn, Danish brun, Old Frisian and Old High German brun, Dutch bruin, German braun), **from PIE *bher-** (3) "shining, brown" (cognates: Lithuanian beras "brown"), related to* bheros "dark animal" (compare beaver, bear (n.), and Greek phrynos "toad," literally "the brown animal").
>
> The Old English word also had a sense of "brightness, shining," preserved only in burnish. The Germanic word was adopted into Romanic (Middle Latin brunus, Italian and Spanish bruno, French brun). Brown Bess, slang name for old British Army flintlock musket, first recorded 1785.

Слово *bear* :

> **bear** (n.) Look up bear at Dictionary.com
> Old English bera "bear," from Proto-Germanic *beron, literally "the brown (one)" (cognates: Old Norse björn, Middle Dutch bere, Dutch beer, Old High German bero, German Bär), **from PIE *bher-** (3) "bright, brown" (see brown (adj.)).
>
> Greek arktos and Latin ursus retain the PIE root word for "bear" (*rtko; see Arctic), but it is believed to have been ritually replaced in the northern branches because of hunters' taboo on names of wild animals (compare the Irish equivalent "the good calf," Welsh "honey-pig," Lithuanian "the licker," Russian medved "honey-eater"). Others connect the Germanic word with Latin ferus "wild," as if it meant "the wild animal (par excellence) of the northern woods."

Comment: Древне-русское АРКУДА (αρκούδα) – это и есть наш с вами современный МЕДВЕДЬ, который произошел из понятия «Арктика»

Comment: Кроме того, в процессе завоевания ариями Северной Индии(13-16 вв.) в санскрит попало МАДХУВЕДА, от русского МЕД+ВЕДАТЬ.

Comment: Вы это от кого узнали? Научный источник представьте.

Answer (score 2):

Черных считает, что медведь - общеславянское слово, и это уже тогда сложение "медовая снедь". Поэтому и  в др.-рус. языке с 11 века мы имеем медвѣдь.

В латинском языке медведь - это ursus, в осетинском - ars . Эта форма уже и.-е. характера (не сохранившаяся, однако, в  германских и балто-славянских языках), но и она не считается исконной индоевропейской.

Answer (score 1):

МЕДВЕДЬ имеет в различных языках свои собственные имена, *нетабуированные*.
Почему в нашей культуре надо считать МЕДВЕДЯ табуированным? 
Почему бы просто не признать, что название МЕДВЕДЬ - это и есть собственное имя лесного животного, широко распространенного на наших просторах? Животного, на которого охотились наши предки (мои сибирские деды - в частности).

Есть две версии, как бы объясняющие происхождение слова медведь в западных языках.

Первая версия - звукоподражательная.

Прочтите слово BEAR, и попробуйте почувствовать в этом звуке то, что обычно и кричит медведь, когда видит опасность или жертву. Но делает это, естественно, не русской или британской гортанью, а медвежьей. По-моему, очень похоже.

Вторая версия в том, что в русском языке есть цвет БУРЫЙ, коричневый, который пошел, вероятно, от неошкуренного бревна (с корой), имеющего коричневый цвет. Ведь само слово КОРИЧНЕВЫЙ означает «цвета КОРЫ», согласитесь.

Вот и получилось, что из БУРЫЙ сложилось, например, немецкое BRAUN - коричневый и BÄR - медведь (средня полоса - место обитания только БУРОГО медведя).

У жителей Британии BROWN - коричневый, BRUIN - Мишка (прозвище медведя в фольклоре), а BEAR  попросту МЕДВЕДЬ.
У французов BRUN - бурый, у венгров BARNA - бурый, коричневый, у шотландцев BROWNIE - коричневый и т.д.

Кроме того, нем.BÄRENGRUBE, которое переводится БЕРЛОГА МЕДВЕДЯ, очень уж напоминает русское БУРЫЙ+ГРЕБ. Другими словами, БУРЫЙ (медведь) ГРЕБ (ВЫГРЕБ) себе берлогу.

Вот такие два спорных подхода к истории МЕДВЕДЯ.

http://goo.gl/YK3c3x (izba-2@yandex.ru, Федор Избушкин)

Comment: Не два спорных, а два бреда сивой кобылы. Кроме безудержного потока фантазии, нет ровно ничего заслуживающего внимания.

Answer (score 0):

Могли. Но, видимо, не называли. Вас интересует, как могли назвать или как называли?
В словарях ответов на подобные вопросы нет, ищите в других книгах.

Comment: Отвечаю.

АРКУДА, сущ., синоним к МЕДВЕДЬ, Словарь синонимов ASIS. 
В.Н. Тришин. 2013. 

МАДХУВЕДА, кирилл. транск. с санскрита - МЕДВЕДЬ.

Что касается датировки (13-16 века), то об этом сказано в Махабхарате.

Comment: Аркуда - это по-гречески. На древнерусском, как утверждают некоторые смелые исследователи языковых глубин - **рыкас**, но я не поручусь, Федор.
Санскрит :  
>**ऋक्ष** back translations:
>медведица медведь медвежонок мишка
>Transliteration
>**r̥kṣa**   
  
Как видно, с греческим есть сходство некоторое. Лат. ursus. 
Дайте сетевой линк на мадхуведу, без отсебятины. Чтобы санскрит, словарная статья, все прибамбасы научные. Без носовских махабхарат.

Answer (score 0):

Да зря так про словари, там как раз и ответы. Например,   в болгарском медведь - мечка.
У нас медведя мишкой называют,  а может, все наоборот, это мишка попорченное мечка?  меча -медуница лекарственная, медонос. еще  меца, мецан - тоже медведь. Brer Bear, Bruin (m.), Goody Bear (f.). 
Мечкар - медведь - лидер (тренер).
Меч основной корень. Мечът.
В литовском неожиданно выскакивает плюшевый мишка - meškiukas.
У нас мечет - раздает, раскидывает.
А у них несет.
У нас мечеть, а в Европе mosque, Bruin-бурый?  А бурый в финском-ruskea!!!!
Ну да, такие вот "совпадения", табу на "русского медведя".
Вплоть до берлоги, где живем.

Почти во всех языках синонимом медведя выступает слово неси. Гугл простенько подставляет два значения  bear из английского? И что интересно получается, надо синонимы смотреть. Вот это самое неси - по всей Европе, и не только, дает корень бер (медвежий) в различных вариантах, их много, очень много, статистика на тысячи слов, куда он входит.

Answer (score -1):

Медведь. Погибающий от холода человек, убив зверя и вспоров брюхо, мог спастись, забравшись внутрь голым. Дом. Соответственно когда человека доставали, он рождался заново. Многие легенды народов мира утверждают: медведь - оборотень. оВоротень Ведмедь. Далее. Я совсем не исключаю возможности использования древними шаманами туши медведя, как биокапсулы для омоложения. Жир зверя особенно целебный. Связка слов мед и медведь  вторична. Да. И обычай съесть печень более сильного никто не отменял. Но мы ведь не папуасы. А медведь не человек.